# Crash when navigating through views

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view

Hello I have in my app a modal view controller which when a certain button is pressed disappears and a view with a UITableView in it slides into position using a navigation controller. The porblem is when I press that button the modal view controller does disapear but instead of navigating to the next view the app crashes and I get the following stack:

```
#0  0x01387a63 in objc_msgSend
#1  0x0634a7d0 in ??
#2  0x003597f2 in -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:]
#3  0x0035a339 in -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:]
#4  0x0652961f in -[UITransitionViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _didCompleteTransition:]
#5  0x002fe665 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
#6  0x002fe4f7 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
#7  0x00e426cb in run_animation_callbacks
#8  0x00e42589 in CA::timer_callback
#9  0x01206fe3 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
#10 0x01208594 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer
#11 0x01164cc9 in __CFRunLoopRun
#12 0x01164240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#13 0x01164161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#14 0x01b5a268 in GSEventRunModal
#15 0x01b5a32d in GSEventRun
#16 0x002dc42e in UIApplicationMain
#17 0x000021dc in main at main.m:14
```

What is wrong with the app? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question neatly or comprehensive with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is happing due to the timing of both events... you can do one thing first dismiss the model view and after that using timer navigate to next view after approx. 3 seconds... like this...

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self performSelector:@selector(moveOn) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.5];


-(void)moveOn

{

    SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
    [secondView release];

}
```